# Problems when i execute gradle bintrayUpload

Tags: android, gradle

This is the wrong information below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':library:bintrayUpload'.

  > Could not create package 'LuMeng/maven/WinchanceHttpUtil': HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [message:This resource requires authentication]
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 24.695 secs

I excuted first step `gradle` build.It's worked. But when i excute the second step: `gradle` bintrayUpload, it shows log above.

Comment: it's my first time upload something to jcenter.